# Best practice to declare character array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, nul

I have to read data from a device which is 4 bytes long so that I have declared array like

```
char data[4] = {0};
```

I will parse this as per index and guarantee to stop at index 3.

> data[0]..data[3]

In this case there is no room for NUL('\0').

I want to know is this considered safe or I should declare array as

```
char data[5] = {0};
```

This array will not be used in str* series of functions.

Comment: It depends of what you project to do with `data`. Certain functions expect a final `'\0'`: `strlen`, `strchr`, `strcpy`... some don't : `memcpy`, ...

Comment: What really that one extra byte will _cost_ you? IMHO, be safe, be idiot proof, go with 5.

Comment: `char data[5];` then `memset( data, 0, sizeof data );`.

Comment: @i486 - How is that better?

Comment: @i486 `memset` is more error-prone than `= { 0 }` because you may get one of the arguments wrong

Comment: @SouravGhosh In production code, the cost of using 5 instead of 4 is confusion. It can't be best practice to guesstimate the needed array size if colleagues (including you yourself in two months) are going to wonder, "why 5?"

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth `memset` is standard way to clean new objects (arrays, structures, etc.). It is better because of readability.

Comment: "standard"? I think you misspelled *lame*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the data to be read is a string of `4` bytes or if it is greater than `4` bytes and you are using `char` as a character array instead of string then no need to worry. Otherwise you have to care about `'\0'`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `char data[4];` for 4-byte data should be safe if you won't use functions that deal with strings like `strcmp()`, `strlen()` or `%s` specifier of `printf()` for that data.

Answer (score 1):

Some rules that I use:

- To store string, should allocate 1 more byte for the `\0` char. e.g `char arr[len+1];`
- To store fix-size data other than string, allocate just as much as you need. e.g `char data[len];`
- If it's quite large, and size change dynamically, then could allocate via `malloc()`, and resize later via `realloc()`. e.g `void *buf = malloc(size);`
- When the array need to be used by multiple function, then declare it as static `char[]` or allocate it via `malloc()`.